# How to query GUID stored in a number field

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a primary key in my table as NUMBER and it was populated using the following:

```
to_number(sys_guid(),'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
```

Now how can I query the table?

Using

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE ID = 2.68819609716248E38
```

does not return any results

Comment: I would like to check if any data into my table is with `SELECT * FROM TABLE1`. So, than you have a look at the output. It could also you should close up your number into `to_number("2.68819609716248E38",'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')` is only a hint.

Comment: the data gets returned with the `SELECT * FROM TABLE1` but if I copy and paste the ID into my WHERE clause, nothing gets returned

Comment: to_number("2.68819609716248E38",'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') gives me an erro "invalid number"

Comment: okay. `to_number()` and `sys_guid()` your own function? Which program-language do you use?

Comment: why are you trying to convert the result of sys_guid() to a number? That seems odd.

Comment: Your number should a plus operator in it like `2.68819609716248E+38` than I get a result of `2.6881961 × 10^38`. Try it out into google with your number `2.68819609716248E38` and than with my number!

Comment: please show the table definition for the PK

Comment: CREATE TABLE TABLE1
(
  RECORD_ID    NUMBER NOT NULL,
  RECORD_NAME  VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL
)

Comment: @MitnickCodeHelper - 2.688...E38 is already a **number**, why are you treating it as an input string? What the OP wrote makes sense (even though it is wrong for other reasons), but what you wrote in your comments makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you had a **raw** value which you converted to number. Now you need to reverse the process.

First convert the saved number back to a string. Then apply `hextoraw`. When you convert from number to string, you must use a format model to request hex representation. Then you must use the `fm` format model modifier, and use `0` as the first digit to make sure the string keeps leading zeros; the `fm` modifier is needed so you don't get a space (placeholder for sign) as the first character.

Alternatively, you could compare directly to a fixed number, but the number must make sense. You show something like 2.68199...E38 as your input. Where is that coming from? Obviously not from converting a raw value to number (like you did with the `sys_guid` values). The value should be a 38-digit integer, with 38 significant digits; your value has only 15 significant digits, so the rest are filled with zeros. Obviously that will not match any saved values.